# Global append lines

Tags: ex-mode, ex-command

Given file *alfa.txt*:

```
10
11
12
13
```

I would like to append a line of text after every line. This is simple enough
with sed:

```
$ sed aBRAVO alfa.txt
10
BRAVO
11
BRAVO
12
BRAVO
13
BRAVO
```

However I am having hard time with Ex:

```
$ ex -sc '%a|BRAVO' -cx alfa.txt
$ cat alfa.txt
10
11
12
13
BRAVO
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*append* only supports a [single line address](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ex.html#tag_20_40_13_12), not a range. Here is a
workaround with *global*:

```
ex -sc 'g/^/a|BRAVO' -cx alfa.txt
```

and with *substitute*:

```
ex -sc '%s/$/\rBRAVO/|x' alfa.txt
```